# MongoDB: Search in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a field in a MongoDB Collection like:
`{
    place = ['London','Paris','New York']
 }`

I need a query that will return only that particular entry of the array, where a specific character occurs.  For Example, I want to search for the terms having the letter 'o'(case-insensitive) in them. It should just return 'London' and 'New York'.
I tried `db.cities.find({"place":/o/i})`, but it returns the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `$unwind` using an aggregate query, then match.

```
db.cities.aggregate([ { $unwind:'$place' }, { $match: { place : {$regex: /o/i } } } ])
```

Answer (score -1):

In simple you find with `$regex` below query will work without aggregation

```
db.collectionName.find({ place : {$regex: /o/i } })
```